# array index out of bounds:7

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class mdar {
    public void cont(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int con = 100;
        int multi[][]=new int [con][6];
        for(int x = 0;x<multi.length;x++){
            for(int y = 0;y<multi[x].length;y++){
                int temp = rand.nextInt(9);
                multi[x][y] = multi[x+1][temp];    //this line is going bad
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<multi.length;i++){
            System.out.print("contester "+multi[i]);
            for(int j=0;j<multi[i].length;j++){
                System.out.println(" has "+multi[i][j]+" ");                
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I deleted my old project and so i was trying to remake it and i can't figure it out anymore :S
Could someone help me out here?

Comment: Dude starting commenting out code, a good and must skill

Comment: I've voted to close. Without knowing what your code is supposed to do, it's very hard to help you beyond pointing out `x + 1` caused the exception. If you can provide further information, we can help.

Comment: Unless he is trying to alias random cells of the multi array from another cell of the multi array (who would do this?), we can figure that multi[x][y] is supposed to receive the random value stored in temp.

Comment: it's just basic code -.-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you meant to write

```
multi[x][y] = temp;
//This would set multi[x][y] to a random int in the range [0,8] (inclusive)
```

instead of

```
multi[x][y] = multi[x+1][temp];    //this line is going bad
//This will assign the int value at multi[x+1][temp] to the variable multi[x][y]
```

There are 2 things wrong with this:
1) x is a for loop counter in range [0,multi.length) [inclusive, exclusive)

```
for(int x = 0;x<multi.length;x++)
```

x+1 is outside the bounds of the array

2) temp is a random int in range [0,8] [inclusive, inclusive]

```
int temp = rand.nextInt(9);
```

however the multi array is defined with a 2nd dimension size of 6 (valid locations `multi[x][0]` through `multi[x][5]`)

```
int multi[][]=new int [con][6];
```

The random variable temp will be outside of the valid range 3/9 times (for 6, 7, 8), therefore you will encounter this error 33% of the time that nextInt(9) is called. Since it is called many times in a single call to cont() you will almost never have an execution that runs without error, however, **it is still logically incorrect code whether it executes with or without error.**

Answer (score 4):

The second dimention of `multi` is 6;

```
int multi[][]=new int [con][6];
```

However you call anything up to 8 on that second dimention

```
 int temp = rand.nextInt(9);
 multi[x][y] = multi[x+1][temp]; //temp could be between 0 and 8 from the random function
```

As such you get an array index out of bounds, in your case temp was 7.

Addtionally your loop goes between 0 and `multi[x].length-1`

```
for(int y = 0;y<multi[x].length;y++){
```

But you call `multi[x+1]` which will at the end of the loop be one larger that the largest index of multi, but you'll hit this exception after the other one (99% of the time)

```
multi[x][y] = multi[x+1][temp];
```

Comment: Also, `x+1` will overflow on the final iteration around the x loop.

Comment: uhm, thats not what i mean indeed. The length of each con = 6 integers. de random goes up to nine

Answer (score 3):

without an idea of what the code is supposed to do, it hard for us to give a solution. The error is quite clear. See in the last iteration of your outer loop `x = multi.length - 1`. So when you ask for `multi[x+1][temp]` you are asking for `multi[multi.length]` which is out of bounds since multi goes from `[0 to multi.length-1]`.

In addition to that `int temp = rand.nextInt(9)` will also cause an out of bounds exception if it returns values 6,7 or 8, since the second dimension of multi must be in the range `[0 to 5]`

Again without an idea of what needs to be done, I can't know if the solution i propose below does what you want to do:

```
    for(int x = 0;x<multi.length - 1;x++){
        for(int y = 0;y<multi[x].length;y++){
            int temp = rand.nextInt(multi[x+1].length);
            multi[x][y] = multi[x+1][temp];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When your

```
int temp = rand.nextInt(9);
```

gives value as "7". You are getting this error. Debug and find.

Answer (score 1):

You geting out of the length of the array, try to do this:

```
if(x+1 < multi.length)
{
multi[x][y] = multi[x+1][temp]; 
}
```

Comment: the x+1 isn't the problem. the x+1 isn't setting x up to one. x+1 != x++||x=x+1

Answer (score 1):

```
 multi[x][y] = multi[x+1][temp];
```

at the end of loop x+1 making it.

Comment: How x will make it overrrun when the the array size is [100][6]

Comment: Array orders start at 0. If you have 100 length that means its 0-99 including 0 and 99, when  you try 100 it give arrayindexoutof exception.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring your 2D array with second dimension 6:

```
int multi[][]=new int [con][6];
```

Valid index of second dimension will be in range 0..5. 
But then you access it with random number like 7 which is out of bounds:

```
int temp = rand.nextInt(9);
multi[x][y] = multi[x+1][temp];    //this line is going bad
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int temp = rand.nextInt(9);
                System.out.println(temp);
                multi[x][y] = multi[x+1][temp];
```

here when temp goes beyond 5 it will give you exception as you have `multi[][]=new int [con][6];`

change the line `int temp = rand.nextInt(5);`

also you have another issue `multi[x+1]`, when you have x=99 that time it will try to make 100 which is causing the issue, remember array index starts with 0